# How to Delete an item after loading the component in QtQuick 1.1

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qt-quick

This question is regarding QtQuick 1.1, qml, GUI creation

So i have created a component with 3 items (image or rect etc.,) Because this is reused in many screens of my application.

In one particular screen there is need only 2 item.

So how to delete that one item after importing the component.

The below code is just for understanding the concept

My component is like

```
//Mycomponent.qml
Rectangle {
    *code*
    item { id: item1; *some code* }
    item { id: item2; *some code* }
    item { id: item3; *some code* }}
```

my Screen file will be

```
//MyScreen.qml
Rectangle {
   MyComponent{ }
   *some Code*
   }
```

So how to reuse the same component and delete just one item from it?

Correct me if my question is wrong.

Thanks!!

Comment: May be you just want to set `item.visible = false`? Just add boolean property alias to the component and link it to one of item's visible property

Answer (score 3):

In most case you can just change the visibility of an object.

```
visible: false
```

or

```
opacity: 0
```

For example you can add alias property for it.

```
//Mycomponent.qml
Rectangle {
    id: myRect
    property alias item1Visible: item1.visible
    Item { id: item1; }
    Item { id: item2; }
    Item { id: item3; }}
```

Then you can do

```
myRect.item1Visible = false
```

in js.

You can delete [dynamicaly created](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html#deleting-objects-dynamically) objects.

```
rect.destroy();
```

Although you can delete statically created object in general it is bad idea.

Comment: I got it. So you mean to set property for items that are probable to change and set visible false for those items... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to further divide your individual items into smaller components, and build bigger components upon them. Will probably give you better re-usability in future components as well because you will have smaller pieces available to combine as and when required. Something like :

```
//MyReusableOne.qml
Item {
    *code*
}
```

---

```
//MyReusableTwo.qml
Item {
    *code*
}
```

---

```
//MyReusableThree.qml
Item {
    *code*
}
```

---

```
//MyBiggerBlockOne.qml
Rectangle {
    MyReusableOne{ id: item1; }
    MyReusableThree{ id: item2; }
}
```

---

```
//MyBiggerBlockTwo.qml
Rectangle {
    MyReusableTwo{ id: item3; }
    MyReusableThree{ id: item4; }
}
```

---

And then use them as:

```
//MyScreen.qml
Rectangle {
   MyBiggerBlockOne{ }
   *some Code*
   MyBiggerBlockTwo{  }
    *some Code*
   }
```

And if you insist on the way you have described, one crappy way could be :

```
Item
{
    property var inValidItems : ['item2']
    Component
    {
        id: item1
        Rectangle { color: "red"; width: 100; height: 100 }
    }

    Component
    {
        id: item2
        Rectangle { color: "green"; width: 100; height: 100 }
    }

    Component
    {
        id: item3
        Rectangle { color: "yellow"; width: 100; height: 100 }
    }

    Loader { id: loader1; sourceComponent: item1; y : 0  }
    Loader { id: loader2; sourceComponent: item2; y : 100}
    Loader { id: loader3; sourceComponent: item3; y : 200}

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        if( inValidItems.indexOf('item1') >= 0 )
            loader1.sourceComponent = undefined

        if( inValidItems.indexOf('item2') >= 0 )
            loader2.sourceComponent = undefined

        if( inValidItems.indexOf('item3') >= 0 )
            loader3.sourceComponent = undefined
    }
}
```

P.S. Code are just for description, not checked for syntactic errors. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: I completely agree with first your idea, but I have around 50 reusable item in my biggerblock 1, and 50 in my bigger block 2. So if i want to remove only 2 or 3 items, which is better. What do yo you suggest?

Comment: I think the answer by @Konstantin would be better for you in that case.